# Como escrever uma Expressão Regular para encontrar um parágrafo?

Tags: javascript, regex

Qual a forma correta de escrever uma Expressão Regular para encontrar um parágrafo?

```js
// Expressão Regular
var minhaExpressao = /<p>.*</p>/;
```

Como posso corrigir esta variável?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a RegExp `/^<p>.+<\/p>$/gm`, sendo que:

- `^<p>` vai assegurar que o início da linha seja `<p>`
- `.+` pega todos os elementos depois da tag inicial, você pode alterar pra como melhor entender essa parte, pra só caracteres, só números, nesse caso é pra qualquer caractere
- `<\/p>$` pra assegurar que o fim seja `</p>` lembrando de escapar a barra

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar esta expressão para pegar o parágrafo caso ele também possua quebra de linhas:

```
<p>[\w\W]+<\/p>
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var p1 = document.querySelector("#div1").textContent;
var p2 = document.querySelector("#div2").textContent;
var re = /<p>[\w\W]+<\/p>/;
var para1 = p1.match(re)[0];
var para2 = p2.match(re)[0];
console.log(para1);
console.log(para2);
```

```html
<textarea id="div1">
   <p>
      Isto é um parágrafo onde as tags não estão na mesma linha do texto
   </p>
</textarea>

<textarea id="div2">
   <p>Isto é um parágrafo onde as tags estão na mesma linha do texto</p>
</textarea>
```

```
\w\W  ->  captura letra e o que não é letra (ou seja, tudo)
+     ->  quantificador que une as ocorrências
```

Veja no **[RegExr](https://regexr.com/3r7au)**

Answer (score 1):

A única coisa que está incorreta no seu regex é `</p>`, a barra deve ser escapada, ficando assim: `/<p>.*<\/p>/`;

Notei que ninguém utilizou um conceito em [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) chamado **retrovisor**, ou seja, você obtêm a referência de um determinado grupo através da ordem em que foi definido na expressão.

O regex abaixo pegará qualquer tipo de tag, generalizando um pouco, mas se quiser especifico para parágrafos basta trocar onde tem `(.*>)` por `(p>)`, esse regex será capaz pegar a *tag de abertura até a tag de fechamento, incluindo o conteúdo entre as tags*.

```
<(.*>).*<\/\1
```

## Funcionando

```js
let texto = `<p>Este é uma paragrafo</p>

<b>Este é um texto em negrito</b>

<b>Fechamento Incorreto, não deve dar match<b>`

const expressao = /<(.*>).*<\/\1/gm

console.log(texto.match(expressao));
```

## [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/60QfkT/1)